# Taking a substring from a string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string like

```
string str = "<abc> hello </abc> <abc> world </abc>"

Output in List/Array :
hello
world
```

Now, I want to extract only texts between `<abc>` and `</abc>`. There can be n number of abc tags. So I just want the between text.
How can I do that.

I tried using split, but it does not give the between text.

Comment: You can use the XMLDocument or XDocument class to parse the string as an XML record then you'll get the text between your <abc> tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use regular expressions (regex), for example:

```
string str = "<abc> hello </abc> <abc> world </abc>";
string pattern = "<abc>(.*?)</abc>";

var matches = Regex.Matches(str, pattern);

var result = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value.Trim()).ToArray();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you could split by space then filter out the two expressions you don't want.
then add the ones you do to a list.

```
List<String> list1 = new List<String>();
string str = "<abc> hello </abc> <abc> world </abc>";
string[] array = str.Split(' ');
foreach (string word in array)
{
    if (word != "<abc>" && word != "</abc>")
    {
        list1.Add(word);
    }
}
```